# How to use Helios backend framework for iOS within a Ruby on Rails app?

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, helios

I have been looking for a data synchronization solution for an iOS app I have been working on for quite some time, and I think I found the solution in the [Helios](http://helios.io/) backend framework.  The first problem I have noticed is there is little to no documentation covering this project.  The only shred of useful information I have discovered is the [Readme](https://github.com/helios-framework/helios/blob/master/README.md) on the Github project page.

Now I know I need to use Postgres in order to use this framework with my rails app which I have converted too.  Next, I understand this framework allows building a standalone app with the `helios` command.  I would prefer to keep my existing rails app that I have spent time building and incorporate helios as a gem in the current project I am working on, which the Readme provides information on.  However I would like to know how I would link up `xcdatamodel` with a standalone rails application because I did not see any documentation on this when reading the Readme.  Finally, are there any valuable resources on the internet concerning this framework?

Comment: I'd love for some more information on all of this as well. :)